# AxShockwaveFlashObjects and ShockwaveFlashObjects from Flash ocx

Tags: flash, activex, ocx

I'm trying to create:

AxShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and
ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll

entering the following command:

aximp C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlDbg10.ocx /nologo

but I get an E_ACCESSDENIED error.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open your command prompt. Switch to the directory that contains the aximp.exe file. Typically; C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin>

Enter the following command (you may need to change the name of your COX file to match your version.

aximp.exe -source "C:\WNDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\Flash10a.ocx"

Look in the C:\WNDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\ directory. Your files should be there.

Comment: Is it required Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The access denied is likely a Vista/Win7 issue resulting from programs attempting to modify files in registered application directories within the Program Files or Windows top-level folders.

The workaround (and it worked for me) is to

- Copy the **AxImp.exe** and your `.OCX` files both to some user-made folder (*eg:* `c:\test\`).
- Then just simply run the command `AxImp.exe Flash10c.ocx /source` from a command line in that folder.

That will generate (in that same `test` folder) not only your two DLL files, but also the `.CS` source file (for inclusion in projects) and the `.PDB` file for debugger symbols. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

It's true that this error comes in Windows 7 or vista. 
You can simply run the command prompt as an administrator and then execute this command from the command prompt. It works this way without doing anything else.