# Hosting Flash movie in a WPF project

Tags: wpf, flash

I want to host a SWF (Flash animation) in a WPF project.

I searched Google and found something. I tried that technique but had some troubles.

In [this article](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/07/hosting_flash_movie_in_a_wpf_p.html), it says:

> **Then, as mentioned in this posting, it is necessary to run AxImp.exe from
>   the .net sdk on the Flash ocx to
>   generate following files.

```
 1. AxShockwaveFlashObjects.dll 
    AxShockwaveFlashObjects.pdb 
    ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll 
    AxShockwaveFlashObjects.cs In Visual
    Studio, add the references to the
    AxShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and
    ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll generated
    by aximp**
```

But I couldn't understand this. Can anyone write it out step by step? I am new to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

you could look at the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) class. then have your flash on a html page that the browser control is pointed at.

Answer (score 0):

Busra, take a look at [AxShockwaveFlashObjects and ShockwaveFlashObjects from Flash ocx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453654/axshockwaveflashobjects-and-shockwaveflashobjects-from-flash-ocx)

I think that has what you are looking for.
Essentially, you need to open a dos prompt, and run 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Window
s\v7.0A\Bin\aximp.exe" Flash10n.ocx /nologo
Generated Assembly: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll

Generated Assembly: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\AxShockwaveFlashObjects.d
ll

Keeping in mind, you're paths may very by if your machine is 32bit, and on where the visual studio sdk is installed on your machine.

@Blounty, I don't think that was his intent. He wants to run the actual flash file inside his WPF application.