# sample of embedding flash in windows form using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flash

I have a swf file (little animation) created in swish and I want to put it in my windows form app like a header, I was reviewing the below link but it doesn't say too much, could someone give an example of how to do this?

[Embedding Flash in a Windows Forms .NET app](http://weblogs.asp.net/twalters/archive/2003/12/29/46265.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is to an old page. (Circa 2003)

Next, there is a SO question similar to this: [AxShockwaveFlashObjects and ShockwaveFlashObjects from Flash ocx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453654/axshockwaveflashobjects-and-shockwaveflashobjects-from-flash-ocx)

To get the two DLL Files needed, do the following:

```
Open your command prompt. Switch to the directory that contains the aximp.exe file. Typically; C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin>

Enter the following command (you may need to change the name of your COX file to match your version.

aximp.exe -source "C:\WNDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\Flash10a.ocx"

Look in the C:\WNDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\ directory. Your files should be there.
```

Add these two files as reference in Visual Studio.

Here is a sample app on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/5815e676-50b0-47f4-964a-c1bcebfdb9a4