# AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects missing in COM objects

Tags: wpf, flash, axshockwaveflash

I am trying to run SWF game in my WPF application. This game accepts some variables which should be constantly updated (about 100 times a second).  I did some research and I know that basically there are 2 possibilities to run SWF in WPF:

1. Embed WebBrowser and pass path to the SWF file.

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // fixes warning about ActiveX security
            string C_Drive_local = "file://127.0.0.1/c$/";
 
            // path of the flash file, here its in C:\DemoContent\bounce.swf
            Uri swfPath = new Uri( C_Drive_local + "DemoContent/bounce.swf");
 
            // load it in the browser
            MySWFBrowser.Source = swfPath;
        }
```

2. Use WindowsFormsHost to host an AxShockwaveFlash control

```
        private void FlashLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsFormsHost formHost = new WindowsFormsHost();

            AxShockwaveFlash axShockwaveFlash = new AxShockwaveFlash();

            formHost.Child = axShockwaveFlash;

            mainGrid.Children.Add(formHost);

            string flashPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            flashPath += @"\game.swf";
            
            axShockwaveFlash.Movie = flashPath;
        }
```

I would like to try with  AxShockwaveFlash since it provides methods for setting variables but in my COM objects I can not see AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll
I tried to install several different versions of Flash Player but without success. I cannt find any information about it. How can I get AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll ? What should I install to have it?

Comment: **(1)** Does your computer have **aximp.exe** (search via Start button)? **(2)** Download the Internet Explorer version of Flash. Go to  https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ and choose the OS as `Win7 / Vista / XP` then select `FP32 - ActiveX`... **(3)** After installing you will have an OCX file at your Windows' system32 folder eg: `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash`. That OCX file is what you provide to **aximp.exe** and it will generate the two DLL files and you should find them in WinForms as a component.

Comment: PS: If not **aximp.exe**is not available then you must download the .Net Framework (it's a utility file installed in the Framework / Visual Studio folder).

Comment: @VC.One
1) I have aximp.exe 
2) I Downloaded that particular version
3) How to generate these dll? I still dont see it in winforms components

Comment: **(3)** `aximp.exe -source "C:\WNDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\yourFlash.ocx"`

Comment: Also see if [maybe this answer helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870621/2057709).

Comment: @VC.One I was able to generate these DLLs and also I registered Flash.ocx but even if I reference these libraries in my project I am unable to load them on runtime ( I tried both 32 and 64 build)

Comment: _"I am unable to load them on runtime"_ but it's not obvious what you've tried. Use the [**update** option](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64572165/edit) to show your code that can be tested or improved (_eg:_ show us how to recreate your problem) ... PS: Does [**this tutorial**](https://codescratcher.com/flash/play-flash-in-windows-forms/) help you?